# How to prevent window from loosing focus when receiving a grabbed key from X11

Tags: qt5, x11, xlib

My window calls `hide()` when a `QEvent::FocusOut` is received. Simultaniously I want its visibility to be toggled if a hotkey is pressed. Now I have the following problem: Pressing the hotkey, registered with `XGrabKex(...)` seems to steel the focus of my app. Resulting in an unwanted behaviour. If my app is visible the hotkeyevent steels focus, which results in a `QEvent::FocusOut`, which hides my app, and after that the hotkey is received which toggles visibility (shows) my app. I.e. my app does not hide when pressing the hotkey.

Is there a way to tell the x window system to not steel the focus when a grabbed key is pressed? Or are there other possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work in a "proper" way:

```
bool MainWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *)
{
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    if (eventType == "xcb_generic_event_t")
    {
        xcb_generic_event_t* event = static_cast<xcb_generic_event_t *>(message);
        switch (event->response_type & 127)
        {
        case XCB_FOCUS_OUT: {
            xcb_focus_out_event_t *fe = (xcb_focus_out_event_t *)event;
            if ((fe->mode==XCB_NOTIFY_MODE_GRAB && fe->detail==XCB_NOTIFY_DETAIL_NONLINEAR)
                    || (fe->mode==XCB_NOTIFY_MODE_NORMAL && fe->detail==XCB_NOTIFY_DETAIL_NONLINEAR ))
                hide();
            break;
        }
        }
    }
#endif
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different methods.

1. Use `XQueryKeymap` to see which keys are pressed. For instance, when you get a `FocusOut` event, call `XQueryKeymap` and see if your hotkey is pressed. If it is not, hide the window; if it is, don't hide it and wait for the hotkey event.
2. Delay hiding on `FocusOut` by 100 or so milliseconds. Cancel hiding if you either get the hot key or get your focus back during this time interval.

Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270420/why-xgrabkey-generates-extra-focus-out-and-focus-in-events) for useful info.